# New mongoose boolean attribute, everyone at true, default is false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I have a UserModel, used in production. I want to add a boolean attribute (isRegistered). For people already on my platform, I want this new attribute to be true. For new users, I want it to be false by default.

How can I put `default: false` to my mongoose model but true for people already here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Update first your collection in mongodb by adding the new attribute, and then update your application with new model ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ot wait until you deploy your new application.  Then, *after* you've deployed and you're setting the `isRegistered` field to true you can run the command to update all the documents which don't have that field set.

```
db.collection.update({
    isRegistered: { $exists: false }
}, {
    isRegistered: true
}, {
    multi: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks ! $exists do the tricks here. It will check if the value is only from default or already set.
I add a thing I discover while searching for a solution : if you set a default value, all created documents will have this value in MongoDb and not only through Mongoose

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- 1) Add a `default: false` to your `isRegistred` attribute in your Mongoose model
- 2) Run a query to update `isRegistered` to `true` for each person that registered on your platform before a certain date and time (for instance, the moment you deployed your updated model into production)

This way, all your old users will be marked as already registered, while the future ones will not. I am assuming you or MongoDB is keeping track of the date where a person registred.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema would be something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    isRegistered: { type: boolean, default: false }
});
```

Due to this, by default, all the users will have `isRegistered` field to be `false`

And the documents which have already been inserted to your `User` collection would not have the field `isRegistered`. So you can update all the documents in your collection to include that field.

So you can do the following to add the `isRegistered` field to all the documents in your `User` collection. Something like this:

```
var conditions = {},
    update = { isRegistered: true },
    options = { multi: true };

UserSchema.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
function callback (err, numAffected) {
    // numAffected is the number of updated documents
});
```